# Hyperlinks Only Link to Internal Site

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am just starting to code HTML and I am testing the following very simple code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

However, it always thinks that the link between quotation marks is a file located locally in my website, so I end up getting an error page with the URL bar reading:

```
www.example.com/"http://www.google.com"
```

Obviously I am doing something silly, because this is really silly. How would I get my hyperlink to actually take me to Google (or whatever other website I wanted)?

EDIT: Since I have been told I shouldn't be getting an error and that I must not have specified something, here is my entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<Head>
<title>My Website</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="This is a website where I dump random stuff I am interested in.">

<Body>
<h1>My Website</h1>
<p>
<a href=www.google.com>Google</a>
</p>
</Body>

</Head>
</HTML>
```

Comment: your href is correct. If you are getting an error it is because of something else that you have not shown in the question.

Comment: I have edited with the code of the entire file I am working with.

Comment: you need to change: www.google.com -> "www.google.com"

Comment: I have switched between using quotations and omitting them.  It does not work.

Comment: please refer to this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your full code, you are missing quote marks around the link. This isn't your problem though, you need to add `https://` to the link for the browser to recognize it as an external link.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```